# How to read CSV specific item and add row with this item to the list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I have csv file:

```
Type;Manufacturer;Model;Spec;Price
HDD;Seagate;Barracuda;1TB;35,99
HDD;Seagate;Barracuda;2TB;79
HDD;Intenso;;5TB;140
HDD;Fujitsu;;1TB;71,4
HDD;Western Digital;Purple Series;2TB;59
SSD;Western Digital;Blue;500GB;57
SSD;Samsung;970 EVO Plus;500GB;90,99
RAM;Corsair;Vengeance LPX;16GB;99
```

and I need to find row by specific item and append it to list
I tried:

```
import csv
with open('komponentes.csv') as f:
    elements = [i.split(';')[0] for i in elements] 
    print(elements)
f.close
SDD=[] #SSD and HDD
RAM=[]
GPU=[]
CPU=[]
MB=[]
BP=[]
KRP=[]
for el in elements:
    if el=='SSD':
        SDD.append(elements)
        print(SDD)
```

but it gives me:

```
['Veids', 'HDD', 'HDD', 'HDD', 'HDD', 'HDD', 'SSD', 'SSD', 'RAM', 'RAM', 'RAM', 'RAM', 'GPU', 'GPU', 'GPU', 'GPU', 'CPU', 'CPU', 'CPU', 'CPU', 'MB', 'MB', 'MB', 'MB', 'PSU', 'PSU', 'PSU', 'PSU', 'Korpuss', 'Korpuss', 'Korpuss', 'Korpuss', 'Disc', 'Disc']
[['Veids', 'HDD', 'HDD', 'HDD', 'HDD', 'HDD', 'SSD', 'SSD', 'RAM', 'RAM', 'RAM', 'RAM', 'GPU', 'GPU', 'GPU', 'GPU', 'CPU', 'CPU', 'CPU', 'CPU', 'MB', 'MB', 'MB', 'MB', 'PSU', 'PSU', 'PSU', 'PSU', 'Korpuss', 'Korpuss', 'Korpuss', 'Korpuss', 'Disc', 'Disc']]
[['Veids', 'HDD', 'HDD', 'HDD', 'HDD', 'HDD', 'SSD', 'SSD', 'RAM', 'RAM', 'RAM', 'RAM', 'GPU', 'GPU', 'GPU', 'GPU', 'CPU', 'CPU', 'CPU', 'CPU', 'MB', 'MB', 'MB', 'MB', 'PSU', 'PSU', 'PSU', 'PSU', 'Korpuss', 'Korpuss', 'Korpuss', 'Korpuss', 'Disc', 'Disc'], ['Veids', 'HDD', 'HDD', 'HDD', 'HDD', 'HDD', 'SSD', 'SSD', 'RAM', 'RAM', 'RAM', 'RAM', 'GPU', 'GPU', 'GPU', 'GPU', 'CPU', 'CPU', 'CPU', 'CPU', 'MB', 'MB', 'MB', 'MB', 'PSU', 'PSU', 'PSU', 'PSU', 'Korpuss', 'Korpuss', 'Korpuss', 'Korpuss', 'Disc', 'Disc']]
```

and i need something like:

```
["SSD;Western Digital;Blue;500GB;57", "HDD;Seagate;Barracuda;2TB;79"]
["RAM;Corsair;Vengeance LPX;16GB;99"]
```

Comment: Why don't you use the `csv` module? You import it, but don't use it.

Comment: There are no commas in the file, what's the purpose of `i.split(',')[0]`?

Comment: `elements` only contains the first field of the CSV rows. How do you expect to get the whole line into the result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `csv` module to parse it. Then compare `row[0]` with your strings that you use to append to the corresponding lists.

```
import csv

with open('komponentes.csv') as f:
    csvf = csv.reader(f, sep=';')
    for row in csvf:
        row_string = ';'.join(row)
        if row[0] in ('SDD', 'HDD'):
            SDD.append(row_string)
        elif row[0] == 'RAM':
            RAM.append(row_string)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just need something like

```
["SSD;Western Digital;Blue;500GB;57", "HDD;Seagate;Barracuda;2TB;79"]
["RAM;Corsair;Vengeance LPX;16GB;99"]
```

Just do

```
with open('komponentes.csv') as f:
    result = f.readlines()
```